# Convert IObservable<MyObject> into IObservable<bool>

Tags: c#, observable

I need to convert my `IObservable<MyObject>` (coming from Akavache) into another `IObservable`, in my case an `IObservable<bool>`.

I have no clue how to do that. The following code snippet is obviously wrong... Can you give me some hints to get it right?

```
public IObservable<bool> IsMyObjectGreat() {
    var newObservable = GetMyObject().Subscribe<MyObject>((obj) => {
        if(obj?.Count > 5) {
           // set true in my observable
        }
        // set false in my new observable
    });
    return newObservable;
}
```

Comment: It's quite easy if `GetMyObject`is an Observable. Just `map` it:
`GetMyObject().map((obj) => obj.Count > 5)`

Comment: Thanks Luka! But it's not working here, because I cannot call `IObservable.map(..)` Do I have to import something like Linq? Or is it possible you have Java or F# in mind?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I meant `Select`. It's called `map` in all the other Rx Implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetMyObject().Select(obj => { if (obj?.Count > 5) { return true; } return false; }).AsObservable();
```

Comment: Thanks Daniele! Working like a charm! :)